# Binding Combobox to ViewModelMain method

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox

I have a combo box that I need to populate when a user selects it from data stored in a variable in my ViewModelMain class, but can't get it working.

My ViewModel looks like this and the GetMessagesTypes() method is the one I am interested in. The messageType variable returns a list of MessageTypes which I need to bind to my combo box.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

```
  namespace Toolbox.ViewModel
{
    [ImplementPropertyChanged]
    internal class ViewModelMain
    {
        #region Fields
        private readonly IActionLogRepository m_ActionLogRepository;
        #endregion

        #region Properties
        public DateTime QueryFromDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime QueryToDate { get; set; }
        public int TopXRecords { get; set; }
        public ICommand SearchTopXRecord { get; private set; }
        public ICommand GetListOfmessageTypes { get; set; }
        public ICommand SearchDateCommand { get; private set; }
        public object SelectedMessageBody { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<IActionLog> Messages { get; set; }

        #endregion

        #region Constructor
        //Should use injection container
        public ViewModelMain(IActionLogRepository actionLogRepository)
        {
            QueryToDate = DateTime.Now;
            QueryFromDate = DateTime.Now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(1));
            m_ActionLogRepository = actionLogRepository;
            Messages = new ObservableCollection<IActionLog>();
            SearchDateCommand = new SimpleCommand { ExecuteDelegate = SetActionLogsBetweenDates };
            SearchTopXRecord = new SimpleCommand { ExecuteDelegate = SetActionLogsForTopXRecords };

            SetActionLogs();
            //GetMessagesTypes();
        }
        #endregion

        #region Methods
        private void SetActionLogs()
        {
            List<IActionLog> actionLogs = m_ActionLogRepository.GetAllActionLogs();

            Messages.Clear();
            actionLogs.ForEach(actionLog => Messages.Add(actionLog));
        }

        public void SetActionLogsBetweenDates()
        {
            List<IActionLog> actionLogs = m_ActionLogRepository.GetAllActionLogsBetweenDates(QueryFromDate, QueryToDate);

            Messages.Clear();
            actionLogs.ForEach(actionLog => Messages.Add(actionLog));
        }

        public void SetActionLogsForTopXRecords()
         {
             List<IActionLog> actionLogs = m_ActionLogRepository.GetAllTopXActionLogs(TopXRecords);

            Messages.Clear();
            actionLogs.ForEach(actionLog => Messages.Add(actionLog));
        }

        public string GetMessagesTypes()
        {

            List<IActionLog> actionLogMessageType = m_ActionLogRepository.GetAllActionLogs();

            var messageType = (
                from messageTypes in actionLogMessageType
                select messageTypes.MessageType).Distinct();
            return messageType.ToString(); //Return Messages types
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WPF, we don't data bind method results. Instead, you have a few choices to make... the thing is that you need to get execution in the view model so that you can call your method. Once you have called your method, you should set the resulting value into a collection property that you data bind to the `ComboBox.ItemsSource` property.

One way that you can get execution into the view model is to data bind a property to a `SelectedItem` property (or similar). Each time the selected item changes, execution will go to the view model and you could call your method. Take this small example:

```
private YourDataType selectedItem = new YourDataType();
public YourDataType SelectedItem
{
    get { return selectedItem; }
    set 
    {
        selectedItem = value; 
        NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedItem"); 
        DoSomethingWithSelectedItem(SelectedItem); // <-- Call method here
    }
}
```

Another way to get execution into the view model at the correct point might be implement some sort of `ICommand` that gets fired under a particular set of circumstances... that's up to you, as long as you get execution into the view model at the correct time for you to call your method and populate the results into a `public` collection property.

You haven't explained your situation very clearly, so this solution may not be a perfect fit for you, but you should get the idea and be able to abstract a solution from this.